# Line chart with means and CIs in Stata

Tags: confidence-interval, stata

I have a data set with effect estimates for different points in time (for 1 month, 2 months, 6 months, 12 months and 18 months) and its standard errors. Now I want to plot the means for each period and the corresponding CIs around the means.

My sample looks like:

```
effect  horizon   se
0.03    1         0.2
0.02    6         0.01
0.01    6         0.3
0.00    1         0.4
0.04    18        0.2
0.02    2         0.05
0.01    2         0.02
...     ...
```

The means of the effects for each horizon lead to 5 data points that I want to plot in a line chart together with the confidence intervals. I tried this:

```
egen means = mean(effect), by(horizon)
line means horizon
```

But how can I add the symmetric confidence bands?  Such that I get something that looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely certain that this makes sense statistically, but here's how I might do this:

```
gen variance = se^2
collapse (mean) effect (sum) SV = variance (count) noobs = effect, by(horizon)
gen se_mean = sqrt(SV*(1/noobs)^2)
gen LB = effect - 1.96*se_mean
gen UB = effect + 1.96*se_mean

twoway (rline LB UB horizon, lpattern(dash dash)) (line effect horizon, lpattern(solid)), yline(0, lcolor(gray))
```

Which yields:

[image]

To get the SE of the mean effects *T*̅, I am using the formula

*V*(*T*̅) = 1/(*n*<sup>2</sup>) Σ<sub>*i*</sub><sup>*n*</sup> *V*(*T*<sub>*i*</sub>)

(which assumes the covariances of the effects are all zero). I then take the square root to get the SE of *T*̅.

Comment: If it doesn't make statistical sense, why even propose it?  What exactly does this code do, anyway?

Comment: This code averages the effects and their standard errors, which assumes independence among of the effects. It also assumes normality to get the the 1.96 critical values for the CIs. Then it plots the average effect together with the CI.

Comment: It's hard to determine what the OP wants, but it seems to be for a way to erect confidence intervals around means of data where each value has its own SE.   In any event, it is hard to conceive of any situation where averaging SEs would be a valid way to combine them into anything meaningful, regardless of any assumptions of independence.

Comment: @whuber You're right. I did the math wrong. I amended the code to do something more sensible (hopefully).